# Session reset when redirecting to /

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, web-applications

I have an Express 4 powered web application that makes use of express-session.

In my front end, I have a "Home" button users may click to return to root. 
However when I do this, my  Express session is cleared out.

My settings are:

```
{
   store: new KnexSessionStore(),
   secret: 'my secret',
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   name: 'my name',
   rolling: true,
   cookie: { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000 }
 }
```

I have tried messing with the `resave`, `saveUninitialized`, and `rolling` properties to no real effect. I also tried using session cookies with no difference.

I am not actually running any code of my own on the `/` route: I simply have an Express static server that is serving a single `index.html` with a React application attached:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use('/', express.static('/my/app/path'))
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on 3000'))
```

As an additional note, if I log in, then close my browser, then I reopen the browser to my application, I remain logged in and my session is still valid (as one would expect). It is *only* when I explicitly navigate to `/` that this issue appears.

My code to navigate to `/` is:

Server:

```
const api = express.Router()
api.get('/redirect', redirect)
function redirect(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.target) { return res.redirect(req.query.target) }
  next()
}

app.use('/api', api)
```

Client:

```
<Button
  className='margin-10-right'
  onClick={ () => location.href = '/api/redirect?target=/' }
>
  Home
</Button>
```

I have also tried setting the `location.href` directly to `/` with the same effect.

Note: The reason for redirecting to `/` instead of using React state to just return to home (using `react-router` for instance) is because I have multiple different React apps at different URL endpoints.  My root URL is basically an app that is a launchpad for other apps, each at their own endpoints, and these other apps need to be able to return to the launchpad.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: can you update your question to show the code that runs when you hit the homepage route?

Comment: @DerickBailey done. Thanks for taking the time to look!

Comment: where in the express app setup is express-session being configured? I think this needs to happen before the `app.use` that sets up the `/` handler

Comment: Yes, it is. I just forgot to include that part.  The session in general is working fine; it's just that it's resetting in this specific instance that is the issue.

Comment: i'm out of ideas at this point, sorry. :(

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @malexdev Were you able to solve this issue? I do have the similar problem.

Comment: @DanielNetto I was, but it was long enough ago that I don't remember what the issue was :( Sorry!